# RichTextBox syntax highlighting

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I am working with [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10675/Enabling-syntax-highlighting-in-a-RichTextBox). It is for syntax highlighting in a `RichTextBox`. I am specifically looking at the function `ProcessLine()` and `OnTextChanged()`, which I have modified as such:

```
protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    // Calculate stuff here.
    m_nContentLength = this.TextLength;

    int nCurrentSelectionStart = SelectionStart;
    int nCurrentSelectionLength = SelectionLength;

    m_bPaint = false;

    // Find the start of the current line.
    m_nLineStart = nCurrentSelectionStart;
    while ((m_nLineStart > 0) && (Text[m_nLineStart - 1] != '\n'))
        m_nLineStart--;
    // Find the end of the current line.
    m_nLineEnd = nCurrentSelectionStart;
    while ((m_nLineEnd < Text.Length) && (Text[m_nLineEnd] != '\n'))
        m_nLineEnd++;
    // Calculate the length of the line.
    m_nLineLength = m_nLineEnd - m_nLineStart;
    // Get the current line.
    m_strLine = Text.Substring(m_nLineStart, m_nLineLength);

    // Process this line.
    ProcessLine();

    m_bPaint = true;
}

// Process a line.
private void ProcessLine()
{
    // Save the position and make the whole line black
    int nPosition = SelectionStart;
    SelectionStart = m_nLineStart;
    SelectionLength = m_nLineLength;
    SelectionColor = Color.Black;

    /*// Process the keywords
    ProcessRegex(m_strKeywords, Settings.KeywordColor);
    // Process numbers
    if(Settings.EnableIntegers)
        ProcessRegex("\\b(?:[0-9]*\\.)?[0-9]+\\b", Settings.IntegerColor);
    // Process strings
    if(Settings.EnableStrings)
        ProcessRegex("\"[^\"\\\\\\r\\n]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\\\r\\n]*)*\"", Settings.StringColor);
    // Process comments
    if(Settings.EnableComments && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Comment))
        ProcessRegex(Settings.Comment + ".*$", Settings.CommentColor);*/

    SelectionStart = nPosition;
    SelectionLength = 0;
    SelectionColor = Color.Red;

    m_nCurSelection = nPosition;
}
```

- My first question is, when I enter into the `ProcessLine()` in `OnTextChanged()`, will I always have a newline character at the end of `m_strLine`? Will the smallest value or `m_strLine` be "\n" and the largest "any#ofchars+\n"?
- And just so I have this right, `SelectionStart` is my caret position if `SelectionLength` is zero, and if `SelectionLength` is greater than zero my caret is at `SelectStart+SelectionLength`?
- I am trying to modify this code to color a whole lot of different syntax expressions, and I plan to go through it one character at a time, for each line. How might this fair when pasting or loading a file of 20k+ lines?

Comment: This is a very basic approach and will not work with larger snippets. It will be dead slow and with a lot of flickering and quirks. You're much better off starting with a better base than out-of-the-box RTF control!

Comment: Might I be better off trying to Regex every line, as they tried to do here?

Comment: Also, Only when loading a file will I have to go through each line. On the other hand when editing a file I will only have to check one line at a time, but still repaint, but only the area of text that the user can see in the textarea. Will this really be as slow as everyone thinks?

Comment: If you want to do it on your own **Costin Boldisor** has a blogpost here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cobold/2011/01/31/xml-highlight-in-richtextbox/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All I can suggest you right now is to use something stable, more powerful and less error prone such as Scintilla for .NET and Color Code. These controls are free and open source. Try them out:

[ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/)
[ColorCode - Syntax Highlighting/Colorization for .NET](http://colorcode.codeplex.com/)

RichTextBox is extremely inefficient for working with large text. Even if you get some decent highlighting, the performance issues will start to pop up pretty soon.

Comment: A good answer, but... Is there ANY way to do this with the RichTextBox? If not, could you direct me to the right direction in creating my own TextBox control? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is going to scale really badly. You should do what DelegateX suggests if your goal is simply a functioning application; if you're in this to learn how, start by figuring out ways to lower the amount of work that gets done. To that end, here are some **general pointers:**

Only highlighting text that's inside the window will be a massive improvement that doesn't have any visual side-effects - its probably also workable to break the text into blocks (by function, method, class, etc) and only highlight visible blocks, even the occluded portions, to avoid issues where an offset starting position affects the highlight. If you don't do this, you will run into situations where the first rendered line is partway through an **if** or parenthesis block, and you have an unbalanced syntax tree as a result.

You still won't be able to handle 20k lines with a RichTextBox control, but a few thousand should be speedy.

Comment: IS there nothing in MVS 08 that could handle 20k+ lines of text? I am just not trying to create something like this from scratch. Possibly only display blocks of text as you said, save the rest in a text file and pull it up when I need it from the file?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that's going to work out of the box, though - again - either of DelegateX's suggestions should do nicely with a minimum of effort. The problem is that dealing with 20k lines of text is inherently complex: changing the length of a line affects every line after it. I believe .NET is rendering the entire block as one giant texture behind the scenes - though i could be wrong - which is going to chug no matter what you do and means you're bandwidth-bound instead of being limited by CPU.

Comment: The method that's easiest on the system is to break every document into 500-line chunks or so, and stream them from memory the disk as needed. This'll make your scrollbars weird, though, so you will need to handle that. And fixing the scrollbars will mean either extending those classes to handle scrolling through space that doesn't properly exist. This is part of why finding a text editor that handles big files is so hard - and it's also part of why most modern development paradigms involve having your code spread across dozens or hundreds of individual files.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue and failed to find "5 minutes ready to go" solution, I have developed my own RichTextBox extension to highlight XML.

I developed it really quick because of time pressure and didn't have the time to revised it - so feel free to refine it.

Just copy & paste the extension code to use with your RichTextBox or copy the whole
application code including synchronous & asynchronous usage

***Extension Method***

```
// Use for asynchronous highlight
public delegate void VoidActionOnRichTextBox(RichTextBox richTextBox);

// Extension Class
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void HighlightXml(this RichTextBox richTextBox)
    {
        new StandardHighlight().HighlightXml(richTextBox);
    }
    public async static void HighlightXmlAsync(this RichTextBox richTextBox)
    {
        var helper = new StandardHighlight();
        var win = new MainWindow();
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            richTextBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new VoidActionOnRichTextBox(helper.HighlightXml), richTextBox);
        });
    }        
}

// You can extent it with more highlight methods
public class StandardHighlight
{        
    public void HighlightXml(RichTextBox richTextBox)
    {
        // Collect Text-Box Information
        var textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
        XDocument xDocument;
        try
        {
            xDocument = XDocument.Parse(textRange);
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
        var documentLines = xDocument.ToString().Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        // Get the Longest Line Length
        int? maxVal = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < documentLines.Length; i++)
        {
            int thisNum = documentLines[i].Length;
            if (!maxVal.HasValue || thisNum > maxVal.Value) { maxVal = thisNum; }
        }

        // Set Text-Box Width & Clear the Current Content
        if (maxVal != null) richTextBox.Document.PageWidth = (double)maxVal * 5.5;
        richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();

        #region *** Process Lines ***
        foreach (var documentLine in documentLines)
        {
            // Parse XML Node Components
            var indentSpace = Regex.Match(documentLine, @"\s+").Value;
            var xmlTags = Regex.Matches(documentLine, @"(<[^/].+?)(?=[\s])|(<[^/].+?>)|(</.+?>)");
            if (documentLine.Contains("<!--")) xmlTags = Regex.Matches(documentLine, @"(<[^/].+?>)"); // Parse comments
            var nodeAttributes = Regex.Matches(documentLine, @"(?<=\s)(.+?)(?=\s)");

            // Process XML Node
            var nodeAttributesCollection = new List<Run>();
            if (nodeAttributes.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeAttributes.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!(nodeAttributes[i].Value.Length < 2) && !(documentLine.Contains("<!--")))
                    {
                        var attributeName = $"{Regex.Match(nodeAttributes[i].Value, @"(.+?=)").Value}";
                        if (i == 0) attributeName = $" {Regex.Match(nodeAttributes[i].Value, @"(.+?=)").Value}";
                        var attributeValue = $"{Regex.Match(nodeAttributes[i].Value, @"(?<=(.+?=))"".+?""").Value} ";

                        if (i == nodeAttributes.Count - 1) attributeValue = attributeValue.Trim();
                        nodeAttributesCollection.Add(new Run { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green), Text = $"{attributeName}" });
                        nodeAttributesCollection.Add(new Run { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown), Text = $"{attributeValue}" });
                    }
                }
            }

            // Initialize IndentSpace
            Run run = null;
            if (indentSpace.Length > 1) run = new Run { Text = indentSpace };

            // Initialize Open Tag
            var tagText = xmlTags[0].Value.Substring(1, xmlTags[0].Value.Length - 2);
            var tagTextBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            var tagBorderBruh = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            if (tagText.StartsWith("!--"))
            {
                tagTextBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkSlateGray);
                tagBorderBruh = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkSlateGray);
            }
            var openTag = new Run
            {
                Foreground = tagTextBrush,
                Text = tagText
            };

            // Initialize Content Tag
            var content = new Run
            {
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
            };

            // Initialize Paragraph
            var paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            if (run != null) paragraph.Inlines.Add(run); // Add indent space if exist

            // Process Open Tag
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Foreground = tagBorderBruh, Text = "<" });
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(openTag);

            // Process Open Tag Attributes
            if (nodeAttributesCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                nodeAttributesCollection.ForEach(attribute => { paragraph.Inlines.Add(attribute); });
                nodeAttributesCollection.Clear();
            }
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Foreground = tagBorderBruh, Text = ">" });

            // Process Closing Tag
            if (xmlTags.Count > 1)
            {
                Run closingTag = new Run();
                content.Text = documentLine.Replace(xmlTags[0].Value, "").Replace(xmlTags[1].Value, "").Trim();
                closingTag = new Run
                {
                    Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                    Text = xmlTags[1].Value.Substring(1, xmlTags[1].Value.Length - 2)
                };
                paragraph.Inlines.Add(content);

                paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), Text = "<" });
                paragraph.Inlines.Add(closingTag);
                paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), Text = ">" });
            }
            richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed version - with handling JSON as inner text and better elements extraction

```
        public static void HighlightXml(this RichTextBox richTextBox)
        {
            // Collect Text-Box Information
            var textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            try
            {
                xmlDocument.LoadXml(textRange.Trim());
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
            var documentLines = xmlDocument.OuterXml.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            // Get the Longest Line Length
            int? maxVal = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < documentLines.Length; i++)
            {
                int thisNum = documentLines[i].Length;
                if (!maxVal.HasValue || thisNum > maxVal.Value) { maxVal = thisNum; }
            }

            // Set Text-Box Width & Clear the Current Content
            if (maxVal != null) richTextBox.Document.PageWidth = (double)maxVal * 10;
            richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();

            #region *** Process Lines ***
            foreach (var documentLine in documentLines)
            {
                // Parse XML Node Components
                var indentSpace = Regex.Match(documentLine, @"\s+").Value;
                var xmlTags = Regex.Matches(documentLine, @"(?<=<)[^>\s+]*");
                if (documentLine.Contains("<!--")) xmlTags = Regex.Matches(documentLine, @"(<[^/].+?>)");
                var nodeAttributes = Regex.Matches(documentLine, @"(?<=\s)[^><:\s]*=*(?=[>,\s])");

                // Process XML Node
                var nodeAttributesCollection = new List<Run>();
                if (nodeAttributes.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < nodeAttributes.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (!(nodeAttributes[i].Value.Length < 2) && !(documentLine.Contains("<!--")))
                        {
                            var attributeName = $"{Regex.Match(nodeAttributes[i].Value, @"(.+?=)").Value}";
                            if (i == 0) attributeName = $" {Regex.Match(nodeAttributes[i].Value, @"(.+?=)").Value}";
                            var attributeValue = $"{Regex.Match(nodeAttributes[i].Value, @"(?<=(.+?=))"".+?""").Value} ";

                            if (i == nodeAttributes.Count - 1) attributeValue = attributeValue.Trim();
                            nodeAttributesCollection.Add(new Run { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green), Text = $"{attributeName}" });
                            nodeAttributesCollection.Add(new Run { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown), Text = $"{attributeValue}" });
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Initialize IndentSpace
                Run run = null;
                if (indentSpace.Length > 1) run = new Run { Text = indentSpace };

                // Initialize Open Tag
                var tagText = xmlTags[0].Value;//.Substring(1, xmlTags[0].Value.Length - 2);
                var tagTextBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
                var tagBorderBruh = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                if (tagText.StartsWith("!--"))
                {
                    tagTextBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkSlateGray);
                    tagBorderBruh = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkSlateGray);
                }
                var openTag = new Run
                {
                    Foreground = tagTextBrush,
                    Text = tagText
                };

                // Initialize Content Tag
                var content = new Run
                {
                    Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                };

                // Initialize Paragraph
                var paragraph = new Paragraph();
                paragraph.Margin = new Thickness(0);
                if (run != null) paragraph.Inlines.Add(run); // Add indent space if exist

                // Process Open Tag
                paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Foreground = tagBorderBruh, Text = "<" });
                paragraph.Inlines.Add(openTag);

                // Process Open Tag Attributes
                if (nodeAttributesCollection.Count > 0)
                {
                    nodeAttributesCollection.ForEach(attribute => { paragraph.Inlines.Add(attribute); });
                    nodeAttributesCollection.Clear();
                }
                paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Foreground = tagBorderBruh, Text = ">" });

                // Process Closing Tag
                if (xmlTags.Count > 1)
                {
                    Run closingTag = new Run();
                    content.Text = documentLine.Replace($"<{xmlTags[0].Value}>", "").Replace($"<{xmlTags[1].Value}>", "").Trim();
                    closingTag = new Run
                    {
                        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                        Text = xmlTags[1].Value.Substring(1, xmlTags[1].Value.Length - 1)
                    };
                    paragraph.Inlines.Add(content);

                    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), Text = "<" });
                    paragraph.Inlines.Add(closingTag);
                    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), Text = ">" });
                }
                richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
            }
            #endregion
        }
```